# Creating bootable USB of Sierra on Big Sur fails

Tags: usb, install, big-sur

I'm trying to create a bootable usb of `Sierra` using `Big Sur` with the command

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app
```

but after typing the password nothing happens and my machine eventually becomes unresponsive.

It appears the command creates some loop resulting in a large number of processes being added (see screenshot).

[image]

I've tried it several times with the same result. Disk was formatted correctly etc. so not quite sure why it's happening - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also - usb is 128GB and formatted to extended journaled.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so after days of head scratching I've finally found the article that explains where the issue is - apparently it's down to the installer that Apple provides - one for Sierra has invalid version coded into `Install macOS Sierra/Contents/Info.plist` file.

[createinstallmedia for macOS Sierra is a fork bomb!](https://www.nicksherlock.com/2020/02/createinstallmedia-for-macos-sierra-is-a-fork-bomb/)

Comment: One of many bugs in Sierra that makes High Sierra always the better choice for the same hardware.

Comment: Sadly Sierra is as high as I can go on my old MacBook Pro.

Comment: In case this link goes down: they recommend editing `/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/Info.plist` and change the version number to the one you find by running `strings "/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia" | grep 12`, e.g. 12.6.06 to 12.6.03.